# Migrate shows error with startproject built site - Django 1.8.2 Windows

Tags: python, django

So I was hoping to build something simple with Django and this was my very first line of code with Python, I'm a noob but I have worked with other platforms.

I did like the tutorials said and installed Django into my system did the code tests to see if it is working, passed. Django, setuptool and pip are all installed and path variables are all set.

I did

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

It worked.

And I went and did

```
python manage.py migrate
```

And I got an error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "c:\Users\Sworup\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packa
ges\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "c:\Users\Sworup\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packa
ges\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "c:\Users\Sworup\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packa
ges\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 190, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "c:\Users\Sworup\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packa
ges\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 40, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "c:\Users\Sworup\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\importlib\
__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 661, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\Users\Sworup\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packa
ges\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 19, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.autodetector import MigrationAutodetector
  File "c:\Users\Sworup\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packa
ges\django\db\migrations\autodetector.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.questioner import MigrationQuestioner
  File "c:\Users\Sworup\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packa
ges\django\db\migrations\questioner.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .loader import MIGRATIONS_MODULE_NAME
  File "c:\Users\Sworup\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packa
ges\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder
  File "c:\Users\Sworup\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packa
ges\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 9, in <module>
    class MigrationRecorder(object):
  File "c:\Users\Sworup\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packa
ges\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 23, in MigrationRecorder
    class Migration(models.Model):
  File "c:\Users\Sworup\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packa
ges\django\db\models\base.py", line 309, in __new__
    new_class._meta.apps.register_model(new_class._meta.app_label, new_class)
  File "c:\Users\Sworup\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packa
ges\django\apps\registry.py", line 223, in register_model
    self.clear_cache()
  File "c:\Users\Sworup\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packa
ges\django\apps\registry.py", line 344, in clear_cache
    for model in self.get_models(include_auto_created=True):
TypeError: get_models() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I haven't changed anything with the default code yet. I just wanted to do the migration and then start the server to see the default splashscreen.

Server start command is not working either by the way.

I have no idea what's the problem here, I did what the how to get started tutorial said, Django is embarrassing me not letting me pass the getting started tutorial. :(

Comment: Which Python version do you use? Django 1.9 will be the first to be compatible with 3.5, which might be what is installed when looking at the trace. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django

Comment: Yes I got Python 3.5 installed. I guess that's why its not working. I was suspecting that but I'm fairly new to python wasn't sure. 
Which version of python or Django should I downgrade to? 
Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In short**
To start learning Python and Django my personal opinion is that running it on `Python 3.3` is *currently* the best choice.

**A bit longer**

As written in the comment, I suspect that you are running into an incompatibility with Django 1.8 and Python 3.5. Django 1.9 will be the first version that should support Python 3.5. For a list of supported versions [see this table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django).

Python 3.4 is currently the latest stable Python release, so picking `3.3` ensures that you are not running into minor bugs in third party packages that are not already being tested and updated for 3.4.

Also, and maybe a bit more important: many of the commercial hosting companies that provide Python hosting might not have the latest stable Python available. So it could happen that when you are going to launch your website you will then have to check it with an older version anyways.

**Python 2 vs. Python 3**
To get your code running install either the latest stable `Python 2.7` or `Python 3.3`. The reason is the huge ecosystem of third party packages that are available for Django and Python. You will still get the highest compatibility by going with Python 2.7. That said, Python 3 is the future and support among the widely used libraries and packages is very high so that it is fine using it in the majority of use cases.

Just remember that anytime you are looking at a new package that you want to install (e.g. with `pip install <package_name>`, check that the package is compatible with Python 3. There is usually a comment about it in the `README`, so this info is easy to find.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll install Python 3.3 and try again.