# Getting Error on Running brand New project from Pycharm on Mac

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am Very new to `Django 1.8`

I have install Python 2.7 ,2.6 and 3.5

I tried  creating project with all version.

I created project in `PyCharm` using `Django` everything is ok.

Now I Run the project and I got huge error

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5 /Users/nileshjarad/Python/Django/First/manage.py runserver 8000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nileshjarad/Python/Django/First/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 190, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 40, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 661, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/runserver.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.core.management.commands.runserver import \
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 14, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.executor import MigrationExecutor
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .loader import MigrationLoader
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 9, in <module>
    class MigrationRecorder(object):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 23, in MigrationRecorder
    class Migration(models.Model):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 309, in __new__
    new_class._meta.apps.register_model(new_class._meta.app_label, new_class)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 223, in register_model
    self.clear_cache()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 344, in clear_cache
    for model in self.get_models(include_auto_created=True):
TypeError: get_models() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Help me with this error to solve

Thanks .

Comment: This could be helpful: [Migrate shows error with startproject built site - Django 1.8.2 Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30684836/migrate-shows-error-with-startproject-built-site-django-1-8-2-windows)

Comment: @soon thanks for replying soon I will check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see from your error you have `Python 3.5` install

Try insatalling `Python 3.3` or `Python 3.4` because `Djagno 1.8` not supporting `Python 3.5`

see this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django) for table that gives version compatibility with difrrent version of `Python` and `Django`